# multiple page in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react router v4 for routing. The layout my app is, there is homepage which is for end user. The path for homepage is obviously `/`. There is dashboard section too. One for admin, one for agent and another for owner. They have their own layout from top to bottom. For homepage its working. But when i hit url `/admin/dashboard`, the main page of admin dasboard is not shown. The same homepage is shown.

Here is what i have done

```
const AsyncRoute = ({ load, ...others }) => (
  <Route
    {...others} render={(props) => (
      <Bundle load={load} {...props} />
  )}
  />
);
```

app.js

```
const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  );
};

import Routes from 'routes';
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar userForm={this.handleDialog} />
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}
}

routes.js
function Routes({ location }) {
  return (
    <Switch location={location}>
      <AsyncRoute exact path="/" load={loadHomePage} />
      <AsyncRoute exact path="/features" load={loadFeaturePage} />
      <AsyncRoute path="" load={loadNotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

I want now admin dashboard a complete new page with different layout not children of App component so i did 
the following

```
class AdminDashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopNavigation />
        <SideNavigation />{/* it will have link */}
        <Routes /> {/* it will display page */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function AdminRoutes({ location }) {
  return (
        <Switch location={location}>
          <AsyncRoute
            exact
            path="/admin/dashboard"
            load={loadAdminDashboardPage}
          />
          <AsyncRoute exact path="/commission" load={loadCommissionPage} />
          <AsyncRoute path="" load={loadNotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
  );
}
```

when i hit the url `/admin/dashboard` i get the app page not the admin dashboard page and same with the 
`/commission` which should be a child of AdminDashboard

How can i make my router work for different layout?

Answer (score 1):

From Meteorchef Base, dedicated routing according to the user (`loggingIn` prop in this case):

Public.js, only for non admin, redirect if not :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    if (loggingIn) return <div></div>;
    return !authenticated ?
    (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
    (<Redirect to="/account" />);
  }} />
);

Public.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Public;
```

Authenticated.js, only for admin, also redirect if not :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Authenticated = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    if (loggingIn) return <div></div>;
    return authenticated ?
    (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
    (<Redirect to="/login" />);
  }} />
);

Authenticated.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Authenticated;
```

then in your App, (stateless in this case, but you can create a class as well too) :

```
// import everything

const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact name="index" path="/" component={Home} />
          <Authenticated exact path="/account" component={Account} {...appProps} />
          <Public path="/signup" component={Signup} {...appProps} />
          <Public path="/login" component={Login} {...appProps} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
  </Router>
);

App.propTypes = {
  loggingIn: PropTypes.bool,
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
};
```